# UITableViewController delegate methods being called prior to viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to populate a `TableView` with data from Firebase in the `TableViewController` below.

By adding print statements, I can see that the following delegate methods are being called prior to `viewDidLoad()`, which is where I am loading my data:

- `func numberOfSectionsInTableView`
- `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`
- `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

  ```
  import UIKit
  import Firebase
  import SwiftyJSON

  class MovieTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  //MARK: Properties

  var movies = [Movie]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
  self.tableView.delegate = self
  self.tableView.dataSource = self
  loadMovies()
  print("I'm called before delegate methods")
  print(self.movies.count)
  super.viewDidLoad()



  // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()


  // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
  // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

  // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
  //         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      print(movies.count)
  }

   func loadMovies() {
      print("Loading movies")
      currentUserMovies.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
          let enumerator = snapshot.children
          var image = UIImage()
          while let child = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
              let name = child.key
              let userRating = child.childSnapshotForPath("User Rating").value as! Int
              let imdbRating = child.childSnapshotForPath("IMDB Rating").value as! String
              let plot = child.childSnapshotForPath("Plot").value as! String
              let imagePath = child.childSnapshotForPath("Image").value as! String
              if let url = NSURL(string: imagePath) {
                  if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                      image = UIImage(data: data)!
                  }
              }

              let movie = Movie(name: name, userRating: userRating, image: image, plot: plot, imdbRating: imdbRating)!
              self.movies.append(movie)

          }
          print(self.movies.count)
      })
  }

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      print(self.movies.count)
      print("tableView returning movie count was called")
      return self.movies.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      print("This is called too!")
      let cellIdentifier = "MovieTableViewCell"
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell
      let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
      cell.movieName.text = movie.name
      print(movie.name + "name here")
      cell.movieImage.image = movie.image
      cell.movieRating.rating = movie.userRating
      return cell
  }


  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,55,0)
  }



  }
  ```

As a result, the table view is just empty rows. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Make sure to reload the table at the very end of the closure in `currentUserMovies.observeEventType` in `loadMovies`, in this case right outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by loading the datasource in the `viewDidLoad()` method and then calling `tableView.reloadData()` in the `viewDidAppear()` method

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting up your tableview inside `loadView` instead of `viewDidLoad`. After loading the movie data call `reloadData` on `self.tableView`.

Comment: `override func loadView() {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
}`

caused the app to crash on the first line of the function. I'm not sure how you mean to set up tableview? I'm very very new to iOS. Appreciate your patience!

Comment: When overriding loadView you need to set `self.view` yourself. I just realized you're using a `UITableViewController` though, which sets up the view for you, so actually `viewDidLoad` is correct. Trying calling `reloadData` on `self.tableView` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadMovies()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    print("I'm called before delegate methods")
    print(self.movies.count)
}
```

This may help you, you need to get your data ready before you show it.

```
 self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

is telling your tableView your data are ready.If you need to get your data asynchronously， write

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

after you processed your data.

Comment: No. I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. This is my first venture into iOS & Swift, so I'd appreciate if you could give me more details on how to fix it.

Comment: change the order of your method as what I wrote. Or add the method tableView.reloadData()  end of your method loadMovies()

Comment: TableView is still empty. Instead of a TableViewController, should I use just a regular viewController with an embedded TableView?

Comment: I will be more flexible if you use an property of UITableView, but if you are new to it, I recommend you to use UITableViewController first

Answer (score 0):

You are using a UITableViewController, you don't need to set delegates or datasources, they are implicitly set by the parent (this is the whole point of it).

Call your loadMovies function and after your data is loaded call `super.tableView.reloadData()`. You may not even need to call reloadData if its just static data from a synchronous method, but typically you would be fetching data asynchronously from the backend.

There is no problem with tableView delegate/datasource methods being called multiple times.

Comment: Just tried this, and it's not populating the table. Is appending to the array a problem?

Answer (score 0):

For say first of all tableview delegates are called, then viewDidload.

Then you can use self.tableview.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths , in this method pass though indexes to reload in table view.